# How to get the cell row from validation list in Excel

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, xlsx

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project. I have Language and Category tables, the category table is the child of language. I have a xlsx file to create new categories instead of using a form in html. The steps are 1) downloading a template containing a worksheet with the language list, 2) in a second worksheet, the user can add new categories, 3) upload the xlsx template with the added fields.

The template I generate looks like this(This was done with the write_xlsx gem):

language worksheet:

ID | Name

1  | Language1

2  | Language2

new categories worksheet:

Name | Language

In the new categories worksheet the language column has a list validation pointing to the language worksheet name. So for example, if the user added a new category, it would look like this:

--Name--- | --Language

category1 | language1

I'm reading the uploaded file in javascript with the js-xlsx library. This generates a json that looks like this:

{name: "category1", language: "language1"}

But I need to know the language ID that was selected in the category to correctly save it in the database. I could use the name to search the language in the database but there might be a chance that two languages share the same name causing problems. So what I need is, like in the example, the chosen language was language1, which would be in the B2 position, I need this row position. Is there a way to know that language1 is in the B2 position so I can get the B1 cell which contains the ID?

Comment: smells like homework ?

Comment: What do you mean? That it's too much homework to answer? Or that this is an actual class homework? It's a project I'm working on and I'd be grateful if someone could help me. I'm thinking adding the id in the name field. Leaving it like this category1(1), and in javascript, trimming it to get the id I need. Not so elegant, but it would work.

Comment: I added the row index in the language name field, like this: "1 - language1". so I know which row was selected and getting the id like that. I don't feel like that should be the right way to do it because it would add confusion to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally ended up doing wwas adding the row index in the language name field, like this: "1 - language1". so I know which row was selected and getting the id from this row. I don't feel like that should be the right way to do it but it's a solution.